# Show that $f $ is differentiable in a endpoint

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: [a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on  the interval $[a,b]$. Assume that  $f$ is differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$. Assume that there is a  number $c \in\mathbb{R}$ so that
>   $$\lim_{x\to b^-}f'(x)=c$$ 
>   Show that $f$ is differentiable in the endpoint $b$ with $f '(b)=c$.

Hint: use the mean value theorem. 
I hope you can help me, thanks :-)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684033/42969 (both found in the “Related” section).

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply the mean value theorem on every segment $[x,b]$, $x \in [a,b)$ : you know, because $f$ is differentiable of $(x,b)$ and continuous in $x$ and $b$ that there exists $c_x \in (x,b)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b} = f'(c_x)$$

Now let $x$ tend to $b$. Because $c_x \in (x,b)$, you have that $c_x$ also tends to $b$, so $f'(c_x)$ tends to $c$. So the quantity
$$\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$$
has a finite limit when $x$ tends to $b$, which means that $f$ is differentiable in $b$, and $f'(b)$ is the value of this limit, i.e. $f'(b) =c$.

Comment: but i shouldn't show that it has a finite limit when x tends to b?

Comment: It is precisely what I show... Because $c_x$ tends to $b$, then $f'(c_x)$ tends to $c$, so the difference quotient has a finite limit ($c$) when $x$ tends to $b$.

Comment: Thank you very much